# How to correctly use componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate in React.js?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-props, indexof

I have a problem. I want to search for an index based on a url. Everything is sent to the components as it should, but there is an error after loading:

*Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined*

Data sent from JSON is sure to be transmitted and received correctly and is correctly assigned. The problem is most likely caused by badly applied 'componentDidMount' and 'componentDidUpdate'. How should it look correctly?

The data sent based on the URL of the page is 'this.props.brand'

**Code:**

```
class CarPage extends Component {
   state = {
       isLoading: true,
       carData: [],
       id: null
   }
   findMyIndex = () => {
       this.setState({
           id: this.carData.indexOf(this.props.brand),
       })
   }
   componentDidUpdate() {
       this.findMyIndex()
   }
   componentDidMount() {
       fetch("/data.json")
           .then(response => response.json())
           .then(data => {
               this.setState({
                   carData: data,
                   isLoading: false,
               })
           })

   }
   render() {
       return (
           <>
               {!this.state.isLoading && (
                   <p>{this.state.carData[this.state.id].model}</p>
               )}
           </>
       );
   }
}

export default CarPage;
```

Comment: this.carData => this.state.carData

Comment: @mokk I fixed this and: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined: Line 32

Comment: @DARKVerbalCentaurPL, you must check the carData array length before trying to access carData[this.state.id].model, because on the first render it is empty

Comment: @Nikita Mazur Where should I do this check? In render or in any of the functions?

Comment: render, and any other function, also consider converting to functional components and use react hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method at all. You can do it like this:

```
 class CarPage extends Component {
   state = {
       isLoading: true,
       carData: [],
       id: null
   }
   findMyIndex = () => {
       return this.state.carData.map(el => el.brand).indexOf(this.props.brand);
   }
   componentDidMount() {
       fetch("/data.json")
           .then(response => response.json())
           .then(data => {
               this.setState({
                   carData: data,
                   isLoading: false,
               })
           })

   }
   render() {
       return (
           <>
               {!this.state.isLoading && (
                   <p>{this.state.carData[this.findMyIndex(this.props.brand)].model}</p>
               )}
           </>
       );
   }
}

export default CarPage;
```

It seems that `findMyIndex` returns `-1` and `this.state.carData[this.state.id]` is equal to `undefined`. Check if CarData indeed has a `this.props.brand` entry.

Comment: The code looks much simpler but when I pasted it it returns: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined". So I checked if the data was loaded after removing everything from <p> </p> and it was loaded.

Comment: I pasted every component into CodePen including data.json. Would you take a look at it? Also not sure but maybe the props brand has a brand problem in data.json. https://codepen.io/VerbalCentaur/pen/ZEeJoMo

Comment: How does `this.props.brand` looks like?

Comment: So `this.props.brand` comes from App.js as `<Route path="/:brand" component={Container} />` then go to Container.js where `const Container = ({match})=>{return (<CarPage brand={match.params.brand} /> );}` and `this.props.brand` is that `brand = {match.params.brand}` which is exactly that `http:// localhost:3000/Lorem0` <- this more specifically "Lorem0"

Comment: Ok, then it seems that you forgot to map an object to its brand. I've updated the code, check it out now.